# regexp greedness: shrinking long path

Tags: regex, perl, shell, path, sed

Please have a look at my mind-breaker.

I'd stuck in shrinking with regex some long path, like this:

```
/12345/123456/1234/123/12/1/1234567/13245678/123456789/1234567890
```

I'd like to transform this path to the following form:

```
/123/123/123/123/12/1/123/123/123/123
```

each "directory" in a path abbreviates to only 3 first characters

```
LONG_PATH="/12345/123456/1234/123/12/1/1234567/13245678/123456789/1234567890"
perl -pe "s#/(.{1,3})[^/]*?(/|$)#/\1\2#g" <<<$LONG_PATH
```

/123/123456/123/123/12//1234567/132/123456789/123

```
sed -E "s#/(.{1,3})[^/]*?(/|$)#/\1\2#g" <<<$LONG_PATH
```

/123/123456/123/123/12//1234567/132/123456789/123

I have tried also:

```
perl -pe "s,/(.)(.)?(.)?[^/]*+,/\1\2\3,g" <<<$LONG_PATH
/123/123/123/123/12//123/132/123/123
```

and many another, no "luck" - I still have no idea about.

Please point me a right way to success.

Comment: Do you want to shorten both directories and file? If only the former use: `sed -r ':a;s|(/[^/]{3})[^/]+/|\1/|g;ta' file`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Match up to three non-slash characters and capture them. Then match the rest until the next slash. Replace by the capture:

```
"s#(/[^/]{3})[^/]*#\1#g"
```

There is no need for ungreediness or anything here, because the negated character class is mutually exclusive with the `/` or `$`.

**EDIT:** Although you seem to know this I should probably clarify for future visitors that this will work with either `perl -pe...` or `sed -E...` as you have used it in your question. The regex could also be used as is with `sed -r...`. If you leave out the `-E` or `-r` option, then (as usual) you will need to escape both the parentheses and curly brackets:

```
sed "s#\(/[^/]\{3\}\)[^/]*#\1#g" filename
```

Note also as ikegami points out that in Perl you should rather use `$1` in the replacement than `\1`.

Comment: I got this `sed: -e expression #1, char 24: invalid reference \1 on 's' command's RHS` with `GNU sed version 4.2.1`

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im words fine for me with the same version: `sed -E "s#(/[^/]{1,3})[^/]*#\1#g" filename`

Comment: By adding `-r` you can tell sed to use extended regexp and the () should work. (without -r you need to escape the () with \.

Comment: To use ERE, I think it's `-E` for OSX's sed, `-r` otherwise. Otherwise just escape the parenthesis.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im my answer just provides the regex usable in either perl or sed, which is why I did not include any command in the answer. the `-E` was simply taken from the OPs question (from one of his examples), and I suppose my regex would work with all of the OPs attempts

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what tool you are suggesting this solution for.

Comment: @TLP any of the ones included in the question... i.e perl or `sed` with either `-r` or `-E` option. I think my answer is quite appropriate, because the OP shows two approaches, and my answer is independent of the choice of approach. of course, if you plug my regex into PHP's `preg_replace` as it is then it would not work, but who would consider **this** a possibility? so why would it be more likely that someone wrongly used the regex in sed without the `-r` option?

Comment: @m.buettner I am not trying to be argumentative, and it was not me who downvoted. Perhaps a regex is enough of an answer, but to me it seemed that some clarification would be in order. If it works with all the tools, perhaps you should specify that, and how.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im there you go

Comment: @ikegami should not or cannot? and then `$1` instead?

Comment: @ikegami also re your edit, this is not optional in all regex engines, have you tried it out for sed and perl? plus, the comma has to stay!

Comment: Well, it works (even though it makes no sense to use a regex instruction to "match what the first capture captured" outside of a regex), but it warns.

Comment: @ikegami I see what you mean, my bad. I just picked up on the fact that `{1,3}` is not equivalent to `{3}`, but that doesn't make a difference in this case, you are right! I'll roll that back.

Comment: @ikegami and I also added the note on perl

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
perl -pe's#[^/]{3}\K[^/]*##g'
/12345/123456/1234/123/12/1/1234567/13245678/123456789/1234567890
/123/123/123/123/12/1/123/132/123/123
```

Find 3 non-slashes, and keep (`\K`) them, remove the following characters up until the next slash.

As ikegami pointed out, it is not required to match less than three characters, in which case a lookbehind assertion can be used instead of `\K`. The benefit is that `\K` requires perl v5.10, and I believe look-around assertions predate that.

```
perl -pe 's#(?<=[^/]{3})[^/]*##g'
```

Comment: Perl regex still have dark corners for me and that's great. Thank for this interesting example.

Comment: @ikegami Interesting edit.. if this is used, the `\K` can be exchanged for a lookbehind, with a slight decrease in perl version dependency.

Answer (score 0):

The best way seems to use the [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec) module to split and recombine a path. An intermediate call to `map` will reduce each path segment to its first three characters. This program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec;

my $path = '/12345/123456/1234/123/12/1/1234567/13245678/123456789/1234567890';

my $newpath = File::Spec->catdir(map substr($_, 0, 3), File::Spec->splitdir($path));

print $newpath;
```

**output**

```
/123/123/123/123/12/1/123/132/123/123
```